# The argument type 'dynamic Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a scrollable screen where I could have each different images vertically with a few functions like a star rating bar and maybe a few buttons. I am first trying to insert a photo into the scrollable screen. Here is my code:
`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight:250,
          pinned: true,
          floating: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppLayout.getWidth(20)),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
                  Row( // text
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "review", style: Styles.headLineStyle1,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(25)),
                  Container(  //search bar
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(10)),
                        color: const Color(0xFFF4F6FD)
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppLayout.getWidth(12), vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(12)),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_search_regular, color: Color(0xFFBFC205)),
                        Text(
                          "place, restaurant",
                          style: Styles.headLineStyle4,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

`

The code that gets an error:

`

```
SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildListItem(foodList2[index]);
        },
    ),
),
```

`

The foodList2 List:

`

```
static const List<Tuple4> foodList2 = [
  Tuple4<String, String, String, String> (
    'assets/images/eel.jpg',
    'assets/images/aburasoba.jpg',
    'assets/images/soba.jpg',
    'assets/images/okonomiyaki.jpg',
  )
];
```

`

I tried to find information about SliverList and more information about SliverChildListDelegate and I figured out that this error dissapears when I delete the body. I do want to keep this body so would there be a way to fix this? (I do know that I don't have a _buildListItem in my code right now)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a builder method, you need to use `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` instead of `SliverChildListDelegate`.

```
SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return _buildListItem(foodList2[index]);
        },
    ),
),
```

Also remember that your `_buildListItem` needs to return a `Widget`